Which origin feat matches with each character background in the 2024 PHB?
There are 16 character backgrounds in the 2024 PHB and each corresponds with one of 10 origin feats.
Which feat matches up with which background?

Here's the official Dungeons & Dragons YouTube video discussing this topic which covers some of them for anyone curious: https://youtu.be/_nUsURlGMyA?si=PFw7H5FnloDPvwPc

This appears to be question seeding a low-quality question that we'd otherwise avoid for a future edition which is a mistake we made last time and should avoid.

Reminder to everyone to be nice.

In an effort to stop the waste of everyone's time, the whole thread about topicality has been removed. For future reference, if a comment has been removed please don't just repost it, though feel free to leave a flag if you're confused as to why it was removed. Typically the answer is to remove noise.

This can be found from a number of content creators who were provided early access by Wizards of the Coast and have since made videos about backgrounds1
Backgrounds by Feat
Each feat can be gained by one to three backgrounds. Here are each feat and which backgrounds get them:

Alert feat

Criminal
Guard


Crafter feat

Artisan


Healer feat

Hermit


Lucky feat

Merchant
Wayfarer


Magic Initiate feat

Acolyte (Cleric version)
Guide (Druid version)
Sage (Wizard version)


Musician feat

Entertainer


Savage Attacker feat

Soldier


Skilled feat

Charlatan
Noble
Scribe


Tavern Brawler feat

Sailor


Tough feat

Farmer



1Here is a group of screenshots from one such a video to preserve the source in case of link rot: Screenshots
